# C# Как найти максимальное значение int не используя константу?

Tags: c#, математика, консоль

Нужно найти максимальное значение типа int, используя только математические вычисления,не зная вес типа данных, без константы MaxValue. Тот же вопрос к типу double.

Answer (score 1):

```
int maxInt = (int)Math.Pow(2, 8 * sizeof(int)) - 1; // для int
double maxDouble = Math.Pow(2, 8 * sizeof(double) - 12) * (1 - Math.Pow(2, -52)) * Math.Pow(2, 1023); // для double
```

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос

Объяснение:

int:

- Тип int занимает 32 бита, из которых один бит используется для знака
  числа.
- Максимальное значение без знака, которое можно представить 31 битами,
  равно 2^31 - 1.
- Поскольку используется знаковое представление чисел, максимальное
  значение int равно половине от максимального значения без знака, т.е.
  (2^31 - 1)/2 = 2^30 - 1.

double:

- Тип double использует 64 бита, из которых 1 бит используется для
  знака числа, 11 бит - для хранения порядка, а 52 бита - для хранения
  мантиссы.
- Максимальное значение мантиссы равно (2^52 - 1), а максимальное
  значение порядка равно 2^10 - 1 = 1023.
- Максимальное значение double можно получить, установив мантиссу в
  максимальное значение и порядок равный максимальному. Значение double
  вычисляется как 2^e * (1 + m/2^52), где e - порядок, m - мантисса.
- Таким образом, максимальное значение double равно 2^1023 * (1 + (2^52 - 1)/2^52)

Comment: Объясните, а почему именно так?

Comment: Не надо в комментариях, отредактируйте сам вопрос, а комментарии удалите.

Comment: Все-таки это на грани фола, потому что использует знания о размере и формате типов данных. С тем же успехом вместо `(int)Math.Pow(2, 31) - 1;` можно просто написать 2147483647... Думаю, что в задании имелось в виду что-то иное.

Comment: Исправил вопрос, вес типа данных тоже не известен, кто знает как решить, подскажите.

Comment: @pechenb что такое "вес"? У вас конкретные типы. int 4 байта, double 8

Comment: @aepot вес, в смысле то, сколько бит(или байт) занимает тип в памяти, то есть у int - 32 бит, у double 64. Если я неправильно выразился, поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: У целых типов нет выделенного бита для знака числа, просто при переходе к представлению числа со знаком старший бит получает такое свойство за счет технического разделения на две группы: положительные и отрицательные числа. В беззнаковом виде все 8, 16, 32 или 64 бита являются обычными разрядными битами числа.

Comment: И все таки до исправления ошибки с "Тип int занимает 32 бита, **из которых один бит используется для знака числа**" что в корне не верно, будет минус. Не верите - просто возьмите число -1 и обнулите старший бит, например так `Console.Write(-1 & int.MaxValue)`. По текущей логике должно получиться 1, но результат вас удивит. Исправите ошибку, уберу минус.

Answer (score 1):

Не помню, допускают ли типы `C#` переполнение, но в абстрактном языке можно найти максимум для `int` так, если он допускает переполнение:

```
x = 1
x0 = x - 1
while(x > x0)
{
    x0 = x
    x *= 2
}
x = x0 - 1 + x0
```

То есть умножаем число в 2 раза пока оно не переполнится (уйдёт в минус). Максимум будет тогда в 2 раза умноженное число до переполнения, минус 1.

Comment: Тут пригодится [checked и unchecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/checked-and-unchecked)

Comment: `(int)(~0u >> 1)` :)

Answer (score 1):

Для целых типов задача довольно простая, т.к. битовая структура числа однородна и все биты числа равнозначны. Битовое представление чисел со знаком и без знака не отличается, отличается только интерпретация этого представления. Для использования представления со знаком и инверсии чисел, используется так называемый дополнительный код и инверсия выполняется по правилу NOT(x)+1, для обеспечения единственности нуля. У такого подхода есть недостаток - наименьшее отрицательное число не может быть инвертировано в положительное, т.к. положительное число такой величины отсутствует, но есть и достоинство - старший бит становится индикатором знака числа, однако, в отличие от дробных чисел, нельзя просто изменить значение одного бита, чтобы получить из отрицательного положительное и наоборот.

Для поиска граничных значений достаточно использовать беззнаковое представление интересующего типа, операцию  битового сдвига влево с последующим добавлением единицы битовым OR. Таким образом мы найдем максимальное значение беззнакового представления, а из него максимум и минимум для знакового представления, например так:

```cs
uint test = 1;
uint tmp;
do{
    tmp = test;
    test = (test << 1) | 1;
}
while (test != tmp);
Console.WriteLine($"uint max value = {test}");
Console.WriteLine($"int min value = {-(long)(test/2)-1}");//тут нужно явное приведение
//к знаковому типу для проверки типа ulong, т.к. он является самым большим из доступных
//и не может быть преобразован в более емкий тип со знаком автоматически.
Console.WriteLine($"int max value = {test/2}");
```

А вот для двоичных дробных чисел коими являются float и double задача общего решения не имеет, т.к. нужно заранее точно знать не только разрядность числа, но и количество, размер, взаимное расположение и назначение групп битов в числе, которые регламентирует стандарт IEEE-754.

Как частное решение с опорой на знание стандарта IEEE-754 можно посчитать длину группы бит экспоненты и сделать вывод о том, к какому типу из стандарта относится проверяемый тип. Сделать это можно например так:

```cs
var x = 1.0f;
int k = 0;
do
{
    k += 1;
    x *= 2;
}
while (x != x / 0.0); //тут можно было взять константу "Infinity",
                      //но ее легко получить простым делением на 0
var expLen = Math.Log(k, 2) + 1;
Console.WriteLine($"Exponent length {expLen} bit, x is {(expLen == 8 ? "float" : "double")}");
```

В обоих примерах начальное значение для проверяемого типа должно быть равно единице, т.к. мы исследуем не значения, а сам тип переменной.